# Saving output as XML

Tags: python, xml, ubuntu

in a first step, I process some files in a python script.
Since the script is unchangeable and since it prints out important information, I'd like to save it as xml. 
Until now, I did: python script.py > Out.xml

But: If there are signs like "&" in the output, they should be converted in xml-chars. How can I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either change your script to save in XML format
or use sed

```
python script.py | sed -e "s/&/&ampamp;/" > out.xml
```